# Launch Template name already in use error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My Terraform script does the following:

1. Builds an AMI with every run
2. Builds a new Launch Template (due to it
   using the AMI just created)
3. Builds an Autoscaling group using the
   Launch Template

I want the Launch Template's name to remain the same so that the Autoscaling group can simply update to use the latest version of the Launch Template.

Unfortunately, Terraform tries building a new Launch Template (rather than simply updating the existing one if it exists).  This results in the error:

```
aws_launch_template.launch_template: InvalidLaunchTemplateName.AlreadyExistsException: 
Launch template name already in use.
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I want (without resorting to using name-prefix rather than name in the Launch-Template as that defeats the whole purpose of having versions)?

EDIT: Here is the plan

```
  ~ module.continuous_pull_app.aws_autoscaling_group.pull_asg
      launch_template.0.id:                                  "lt-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" => "${var.launch_template_id}"
      launch_template.0.version:                             "1" => "${var.launch_template_version}"

  -/+ module.create_ami.aws_ami_from_instance.generic_ami (new resource required)
      id:                                                    "ami-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" => <computed> (forces new resource)
      architecture:                                          "x86_64" => <computed>
      ebs_block_device.#:                                    "1" => <computed>
      ena_support:                                           "true" => <computed>
      ephemeral_block_device.#:                              "0" => <computed>
      image_location:                                        "xxxxxxxxxxxx/generic-usage-ami-2019-02-07T212337Z-nonprod-2" => <computed>
      kernel_id:                                             "" => <computed>
      manage_ebs_snapshots:                                  "true" => <computed>
      name:                                                  "generic-usage-ami-2019-02-07T212337Z-nonprod-2" => "generic-usage-ami-2019-02-08T133220Z-nonprod-2" (forces new resource)
      ramdisk_id:                                            "" => <computed>
      root_device_name:                                      "/dev/xvda" => <computed>
      root_snapshot_id:                                      "snap-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" => <computed>
      snapshot_without_reboot:                               "false" => "false"
      source_instance_id:                                    "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" => "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      sriov_net_support:                                     "simple" => <computed>
      tags.%:                                                "2" => "2"
      tags.Name:                                             "Generic AMI for continuous process nonprod-2" => "Generic AMI for continuous process nonprod-2"
      tags.created-by:                                       "terraform" => "terraform"
      virtualization_type:                                   "hvm" => <computed>

  ~ module.create_ami.aws_instance.ec2
      tags.Name:                                             "generic-usage-ami-2019-02-07T212337Z-nonprod-2" => "generic-usage-ami-2019-02-08T133220Z-nonprod-2"

  + module.create_launch_template.module.pull.aws_launch_template.launch_template
      id:                                                    <computed>
      arn:                                                   <computed>
      block_device_mappings.#:                               "1"
      block_device_mappings.0.device_name:                   "/dev/xvda"
      block_device_mappings.0.ebs.#:                         "1"
      block_device_mappings.0.ebs.0.iops:                    <computed>
      block_device_mappings.0.ebs.0.volume_size:             "16"
      block_device_mappings.0.ebs.0.volume_type:             <computed>
      default_version:                                       <computed>
      iam_instance_profile.#:                                "1"
      iam_instance_profile.0.name:                           "role-foo"
      image_id:                                              "${var.generic_ami_id}"
      instance_market_options.#:                             "1"
      instance_market_options.0.market_type:                 "spot"
      instance_market_options.0.spot_options.#:              "1"
      instance_market_options.0.spot_options.0.valid_until:  <computed>
      instance_type:                                         "t2.micro"
      key_name:                                              "foo"
      latest_version:                                        "0"
      name:                                                  "PullTemplate-nonprod-2"
      user_data:                                             "..."
      vpc_security_group_ids.#:                              "1"
      vpc_security_group_ids.34235319:                       "sg-xxxxxxxx"
```

The launch template resource:

```
resource "aws_launch_template" "launch_template" {
  //  If use_spot_pricing is true (which translates to 1), this resource is not created (i.e. count = 0).
  count                = "${1 - var.use_spot_pricing}"
//  name_prefix          = "${var.resource_name_prefix}${var.envSuffix}-"
  name                 = "${var.resource_name_prefix}${var.envSuffix}"
  image_id             = "${var.generic_ami_id}"
  instance_type        = "${var.instance_type}"
  key_name             = "${var.key_name}"
  vpc_security_group_ids = ["${var.vpc_security_group_ids}"]
  user_data            = "${base64encode(data.template_file.lc_user_data.rendered)}"

  iam_instance_profile {
    name = "${var.iam_instance_profile}"
  }

  instance_market_options {
    market_type = "spot"

    spot_options {
      max_price = "${var.max_price}"
    }
  }

  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"

    ebs {
      volume_size = "${var.volume_size}"
    }
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

data "template_file" "lc_user_data" {
...
}

output "launch_template_id" {
  //  There should only ever be 1 instance
  value = "${ aws_launch_template.launch_template.0.id }"
}

output "launch_template_version" {
  //  There should only ever be 1 instance
  value = "${ aws_launch_template.launch_template.0.latest_version }"
}
```

The ASG resource:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "pull_asg" {

  name                = "Pull${var.envSuffix}"
  vpc_zone_identifier = ["${split(",", var.vpc_private_subnets)}"]

  launch_template = {
    id = "${var.launch_template_id}"
    version = "${var.launch_template_version}"
  }

  termination_policies      = ["OldestInstance"]
  max_size                  = "${var.pull_asg_max_size}"
  min_size                  = "${var.pull_asg_min_size}"
  desired_capacity          = "${var.pull_asg_desired_capacity}"
  health_check_grace_period = "${var.pull_asg_health_check_grace_period}"
  health_check_type         = "${var.health_check_type}"
  load_balancers            = ["${aws_elb.pull_app_elb.name}"]
  wait_for_elb_capacity     = "${var.pull_asg_wait_for_elb_capacity}"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "Name"
    value               = "${var.app_instance_name}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }

  tag {
    key                 = "spot-enabled"
    value               = "${var.spot_enabled}"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

Comment: can you update your question with your terraform plan output?

Comment: Looks like a template with that name already exists and it is not manage by terraform. You have to import it or change the name.

Comment: Nope, the template did not exist before the Terraform run.  No launch templates were ever created manually.

Comment: can you post your .tf for both auto scaling groups and launch configurations?

Answer (score 2):

I have also faced a similar issue with launchconfiguration. When you provide a name to the launchconfiguration/launchtemplate during the creation, and if there is a situation when this LC/LT needs recreation, terraform first tries to create the new resource before destroying the existing one and starts throwing the error saying resource exists.

Best way to fix this issue is, do not provide the name parameter in the launch template, let this be a random name managed by terraform and in your ASG use the reference id instead of a variable.

> aws_launch_template.launchtemplate-terraform-name.id

Just in case more clarity is needed in the Launch template. Use nameprifix or namesuffix instead of name.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I don't think that solves the problem I'm trying to avoid, though.  I want to keep the same name, but just create a new version.  Unless I'm missing something, that just doesn't seem possible with the 11.11 version of Terraform.